# Using store_accessor with Paper Trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql, paper-trail-gem

I have a JSON field in a Postgres table that is accessed using store_accessor:

`store_accessor :data, :published`

I want to use Paper Trail to version only the published field. To do this, I tried:

`has_paper_trail :only => [:published]`

But this does not seem to work. Can Paper Trail work with store_accessor, and if yes, how would I get it to version on the published field?

Comment: "But this does not seem to work". What exactly does/doesn't happen? In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: No version is made on updating `published`. Removing `:only => [:published]` does create versions on update however.